# Turning off adaptive scoring selectively

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, gnus, usenet

I would like to
- Turn off adaptive scoring for one usenet group
or even better
- Turn off adaptive scoring for one sender in one newsgroup

How to do it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for _specific programming questions_. This is probably a better fit on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Chris I prefer to skip Beta sites.

Comment: Andrzej, that's up to you, but this question is a poor fit for SO and may well be closed as off-topic. Many Emacs questions do belong here, but I consider configuring Gnus to be outside of that threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Gnus documentation, under [Scoring/Score File Format](http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_94.html#Score-File-Format).

> ‘adapt’
>        This entry controls the adaptive scoring.  If it is ‘t’, the
>        default adaptive scoring rules will be used.  If it is ‘ignore’, no
>        adaptive scoring will be performed on this group.  If it is a list,
>        this list will be used as the adaptive scoring rules.  If it isn’t
>        present, or is something other than ‘t’ or ‘ignore’, the default
>        adaptive scoring rules will be used.  **If you want to use adaptive
>        scoring on most groups, you’d set ‘gnus-use-adaptive-scoring’ to
>        ‘t’, and insert an ‘(adapt ignore)’ in the groups where you do not
>        want adaptive scoring.**  If you only want adaptive scoring in a few
>        groups, you’d set ‘gnus-use-adaptive-scoring’ to ‘nil’, and insert
>        ‘(adapt t)’ in the score files of the groups where you want it.